# fastest way to get array block based on value contained within the block (not working)

Tags: php

https://gist.github.com/jcranny/9465715

I have this array (example)...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [series] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 5
                    [name] => Moto2 2013
                    [slug] => moto2-2013
                    [term_group] => 0
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
                )

            [race_number] => 77
            [team] => Technomah carXpert
            [constructor] => Suter
            [machine] => Honda CBR600RR
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [series] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 6
                    [name] => Moto2 2014
                    [slug] => moto2-2014
                    [term_group] => 0
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
                )

            [race_number] => 15
            [team] => La Fonte Tascaracing
            [constructor] => Suter
            [machine] => Honda CBR600RR
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [series] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 7
                    [name] => Moto2 2015
                    [slug] => moto2-2015
                    [term_group] => 0
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
                )

            [race_number] => 15
            [team] => Mapfre Aspar Team Moto2
            [constructor] => Suter
            [machine] => Honda CBR600RR
        )
)
```

Now I would like to be able to get information from each block.

For example I would like to echo this data:

- **[race_number]**
- **[team]**
- **[constructor]**
- **[machine]**

But I want only to echo this data that is relevant to a specific **[series]**

I have the  **[series]** term_id so this is my key to get the relevant data, but i'm struggling to get my node function work.

This is the function to do this:

```
function node_modify_riders_array($rider_id)
{
        $fields = get_field("rider_series_data", $rider_id);
        foreach($fields as $field_key => $field_val)
        {
            $new_fields[$field_val["series"]] = $field_val;
        }
return $new_fields; 
}
```

Then this is how I am get the series specific data based on the series term id.

```
$rider_series_data    = node_modify_riders_array($rider_id);    
$series_id            = $series[0]->term_id;

$team            = $rider_series_data[$series_id]["team"];
$contstructor    = $rider_series_data[$series_id]["constructor"];   
$machine         = $rider_series_data[$series_id]["machine"];
$race_number     = $rider_series_data[$series_id]["race_number"];
```

But some thing is wrong and I can work it out. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or help me fix it.

Massive thanks in advance, would really appreciate some help.

---

**What the problem is:**

My function node_modify_riders_array is returning null, which is causing my `$team`, `$contstructor`, `$machine`, and `$race_number` too not output anything.

If I echo `$series_id` on my example, I get `6`

Which should pass though my node_modify_riders_array function and display the relevant array values. But it's not outputting anything and I got no errors.

This is my full code so you can see what I am trying to do...

https://gist.github.com/jcranny/9465715

Comment: What is wrong exactly ? Any error message ?

Comment: No error message but I'm getting nothing returned - i'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `object` as your array key and not the `term_id` of your `series` object.

```
function node_modify_riders_array($rider_id)
{
        $fields = get_field("rider_series_data", $rider_id);
        foreach($fields as $field_key => $field_val)
        {
            $new_fields[$field_val["series"]->term_id] = $field_val;
                                          //^^^^^^^^^  <--- add this
        }
        return $new_fields; 
}
```

Comment: Oops, I did have this in but i removed it when I was print_r'ing the $fields var for this question, then forgot to put it back in, but it is back in now and not working still

Comment: That was an obvious mistake thanks for spotting - but still not working. I have posted my full function here... https://gist.github.com/jcranny/9465715

Comment: thank you so much do I was backing my noodle ages this now realise why I was stupid return the object in my array. Really appreciate your time on this thank you.